# Determine the tiles intercepted by a given function in an irregular tessellation

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computational-geometry, tiling, tessellations

Consider an irregular tessellation of the plane composed of convex tiles, such as the following one.

[image]

For each tile, the coordinates of each vertex (black dots) are known up to a finite precision.

Now, consider a function $f(x)$, whose values are also known up to a certain precision. This function can clearly cross some of the tiles, as illustrated here:

[image]

I have to find which tile is crossed by the function $f$ (in this example, the tiles $t_1,t_2,t_5$).

In principle, one can simply use the function $\texttt{inpolygon}$, available in many software, to determine whether or not the polygon describing the tile contains or not one point of coordinates $(x,f(x))$.

However, I realized that the results (i.e. the list of tiles crossed by the functions) strongly depends on the precision of the knowledge of the tiles' coordinates and the function $f$.

For instance, in situations similar to the above example, sometimes also the tile $t_3$ appears to be part of the list of involved tiles, irrespective on the fact that I always include/exclude the boundary of the tile in the function $\texttt{inpolygon}$.

My question is: Given the fact that, to a certain extent, I can increase/reduce the precision of the coordinates of the tiles and the precision of the coordinates of the function $f$,

> **What is the best strategy to solve this task, reducing the number of results strongly dependent only on these precision values?**

Thanks for your help, and sorry in case this is too trivial.